# Gnome Power Statistics, how to change colours?

Tags: gnome, ubuntu-gnome, cinnamon

How to change axis (and text) colour ?
I'm using default dark theme in Cinnamon, and as you can see, axis and text is dark too, almost not visible.

[image: Power Statistics screenshot]

Comment: Thank you for asking this! I also have this question. Using the Adapta-Nokto theme, the font is actually completely invisible!